# Cherrypy bus stopping for some unknown reason

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cherrypy

I've got a CherryPy app running on AWS via Elastic Beanstalk, and one of its jobs is to check a Gmail inbox for new messages, like so:

Edit:

```
# snippet of the code responsible for starting the poller in question
# application.py
def __init__(self):
    ...

    # register callbacks with monitor (token access check, history feed poller)
    credentials_checker = Monitor(cherrypy.engine, self.check_access_token, frequency=30)
    mail_checker = Monitor(cherrypy.engine, self.mail_processor.safe_poll_history_feed, frequency=10)
    credentials_checker.subscribe()
    mail_checker.subscribe()

# mail_checker.py
def safe_poll_history_feed(self):
    try:
        self.poll_history_feed()
    except:
        # no restart needed
        cherrypy.log("Exception in poll_history_feed()!", traceback=True)

def poll_history_feed(self):
    new_messages = self.mail_service.users().messages().list(userId="me", labelIds=["INBOX", "UNREAD"]).execute()

    result_size = int(new_messages["resultSizeEstimate"])
    cherrypy.log("Checking for new messages...")

    if result_size > 0:
        # process message
        cherrypy.log("number of new messages: %s" % result_size)
        cherrypy.log("New messages! Processing...")
        for x in new_messages["messages"]:
            self.process_email(x["id"])
    else:
        cherrypy.log("No new messages.")
        return
```

But the thing is, the thread that seems to be responsible for doing the actual checking seems to be getting killed by something, and I can't figure out what. Log snippet below:

```
[14/Mar/2016:15:32:55] Checking for new messages...
[14/Mar/2016:15:32:55] No new messages.
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:05] Checking for new messages...
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:05] No new messages.
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:15] Checking for new messages...
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:15] No new messages.
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:17] Checking access token.
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:17] Access token still good. Continuing...
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:26] Checking for new messages...
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:26] No new messages.
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:32] ENGINE Keyboard Interrupt: shutting down bus
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:32] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:32] ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080)) shut down
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:32] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Monitor'.
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:32] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'.
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:32] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Monitor'.
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:32] ENGINE Stopped thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:32] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:32] ENGINE Bus EXITING
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:32] ENGINE Bus EXITED
[14/Mar/2016:15:33:32] ENGINE Waiting for child threads to terminate...
# note: the server seems to be responding to outside requests judging by this line and the ones following it.
[16/Mar/2016:04:48:41] Sent internal chat notification to user@userdomain.com, subject [MENTIONED] Client Portal 
...SNIP
```

The rest of the app seems to stay up, as it responds to requests just fine, but it stops checking for new mail completely. Restarting the app servers only fixes it temporarily (less than 10 minutes or so). I've checked I can think to check, but I don't see anything else happening at the time the process gets killed.

Since the question was first posted, I've since increased the size of the instance type, just to see if that fixes things (it didn't). I think I might have messed up logging at some point because I no longer see the ENGINE messages from CherryPy in my logs, so I'm working on getting that fixed right now.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it? I'm guessing that maybe the frequency at which it's checking mail is a bit too fast?

Comment: Hi there, it looks like you're receiving a SIGINT event for some reason: "ENGINE Keyboard Interrupt: shutting down bus"

Comment: Yes, I know that already. Something on EB/AWS is sending it and I can't figure out why. I've checked the logs and nothing else at all seems to be happening when the SIGINT is received by CherryPy.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think we can detect from inside the CP code why it received the SIGINT signal. Stupid question, are you running the CP server in a console that might be terminated after a while? Are you using nohup?

Comment: The code is hosted on Elastic Beanstalk. As far as I can tell its not supposed to terminate anything after a while, and aside from the poller the server is still up and running.

Comment: You sure your installation is not corrupted somehow?